# How do I trigger a re-rendering of a block?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, rendering, wordpress-gutenberg

in a **WordPress Gutenberg** plugin

```
hooks_addFilter_editor_blockEdit = (BlockEdit) => {
 return (props) => {
  apiFetch({url: 'https://example.com/api/'+props.attributes.content
  }).then(_return => {
   props.attributes.content = _return;
   // What should I use here to force re-render the block?
  })
 return ( <BlockEdit { ...props } /> );
 }
}

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'my-plugin-slug', hooks_addFilter_editor_blockEdit );
```

For the above code, my plugin sends the props.attributes.content into an external API, and updates it asynchronously. Visually, as many default gutenberg blocks use props.attributes.content to display the content of the block (paragraph blocks for instance), that content gets updated on the editor, automatically, but not immediately. Re-rendering of the block happens only when my cursor gets off the block, or when I get the input focus out of this block.

What can I add to the above code to force the editor to visually show the updated content as soon as the apiFetch call has succeeded?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work – except the immediate re-rendering when the promise is resolved? And just curious: Do you limit this to certain block types (i. e. core/paragraph)?

Comment: Yes. I'm fine with every results except immediate re-rendering. Actually, what I'm doing is a spell checker for malagasy language. I grab every text for every block and so far, I don't look at block type but at whether props.attributes.content (core/paragraph and others) or props.attributes.values (core/list and likes) are used.

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if it is intended to call your api on each typing in the block as the edit function is called on each state change. What might help is: you shouldn't set attributes directly (immutable), there's an extra method called "setAttributes". I'll post an answer with you code modified...

Comment: Thanks, these snippets are like "barebone" to make the question easier to understand. API calls are indeed queued, buffered to check effective changes and throttled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works for you:

```
hooks_addFilter_editor_blockEdit = (BlockEdit) => {
 return (props) => {
 // Destructure "props"
 const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
  apiFetch({url: 'https://example.com/api/'+attributes.content
  }).then(_return => {
   // What should I use here to force re-render the block?
   setAttributes( { content: _return } );
  })
 return ( <BlockEdit { ...props } /> );
 }
}

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'my-plugin-slug', hooks_addFilter_editor_blockEdit );
```

Still, while typing in a block, there might be a slight delay until your api responds. Also maybe you need to wrap your BlockEdit in a HigherOrderComponent.